# Android match button location with image

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How can I place a button matching it's location with location on an image, the image being resized to fit the width of the screen.

This being the image

[image]

I have added it to a a ConstraintLayout for the MainActivity

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/test"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/untitled" android:id="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The top left corner is located on pixel (100,100) the size of the image is 500 by 500 pixels and the size of the black box is 50 by 50 pixels.

I tried calculating the location by using the width of the image on screen and creating a multiplier using the actual width. But the button is off by alot and I have no idea how to match it with the image.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConstraintLayout viewById = findViewById(R.id.test);

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setId(View.generateViewId());
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        button.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        button.setElevation(100f);

        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(viewById);
        constraintSet.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, viewById.getId(), ConstraintSet.START);
        constraintSet.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, viewById.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP);

        viewById.addView(button);

        constraintSet.applyTo(viewById);

        ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final be.robben.test.MainActivity mainActivity = this;


        ViewTreeObserver vto = image.getViewTreeObserver();

        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                image.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                int finalHeight, finalWidth;
                finalHeight = image.getHeight();
                finalWidth = image.getWidth();


                init(image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth(), finalHeight, mainActivity);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void init(final int x, final int y, final AppCompatActivity context) {

        float mult = ((float) x) / ((float) 500);
        ConstraintLayout viewById = context.findViewById(R.id.test);


        Button button = new Button(context);
        button.setId(View.generateViewId());
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams((int) (50 * mult), (int) (50 * mult));
        float a = ((float) 100 / (float) 500) * x;
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        layoutParams.setMarginStart(0);
        layoutParams.setMarginEnd(0);
        layoutParams.topToTop = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
        layoutParams.leftToLeft = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
        button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        button.setX(a);
        button.setY(a);
        button.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, viewById.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, 0);
        constraintSet.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, viewById.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);


        viewById.addView(button);


    }

}
```

Comment: You will need to add the button before cloning the constraints. This may not be the only thing, but it is the first to correct.

Comment: You could scan the resized image using Bitmap.getPixel.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get the screen position of the rectangle in the image would require you to get the image.
You could not do it in OnCreate because the image is not attached to the screen yet.
You would need to do something like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Matrix matrix = imageView.getImageMatrix();
        RectF rect = new RectF(100,100,500+100,500+100);
        matrix.mapRect(rect);
```

After you get the position on the screen you can add the button
There is no need to use ConstraintSets
Create the Button and populate its layoutParams to position it:

```java
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setId(View.generateViewId());
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams((int) rect.width(), (int) rect.height());
        layoutParams.leftMargin = (int) rect.left;
        layoutParams.topMargin = (int) rect.top;
        layoutParams.topToTop = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
        layoutParams.leftToLeft = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
        ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.test);
        layout.addView(button, layoutParams);
    }
```

This seems like a strange thing to do but this should point you in the right direction.

```kotlin
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.stack1)
        var iv = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
        iv.doOnLayout {
            var iv = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
            val matrix = iv.imageMatrix
            val bounds = iv.drawable.bounds
            val boxX = 100f
            val boxY = 100f
            val boxW = 50f
            val boxH = 50f
            val imageWidth = 500f
            val imageHeight = 500f
            val rect = RectF(boxX, boxY, boxW + boxX, boxH + boxY)
            matrix.postScale(bounds.width() / imageWidth, bounds.height() / imageHeight)
            matrix.mapRect(rect)
            val button = Button(this)
            button.text = "DoIt"
            button.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF3300.toInt())
            button.setId(View.generateViewId())
            val layoutParams =
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(rect.width().toInt(), rect.height().toInt())
            layoutParams.leftMargin = rect.left.toInt()
            layoutParams.topMargin = rect.top.toInt()
            layoutParams.topToTop = iv.id
            layoutParams.leftToLeft = iv.id
            val layout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.test)
            layout.addView(button, layoutParams)
            button.requestLayout()
        }
    }
```

This works

Comment: Thanks but I tried it but the button is much bigger than square on the image.

Comment: understandable. 
This is just the direction you need to go to accomplish this.
There are a few more things you may need to do to get all of it correct.
There may be a dp to pixels conversion.
adding in the transform of where you positioned the ImageView.
Without a working actual example what what you are doing. It will be impossible for someone to give you a complete working answer.

Comment: I think I proviced everything to produce a working example? The imageview is filling the entire width of the screen so shouldn't the transform just match? Sorry for all the questions but I'm quite stuck and don't know how I can get this example working...

Comment: Based on your image and XML I built and example. In next answer